# Constructor Error: What is wrong with my Java/Processing code?

Tags: java, constructor

I keep getting the error code: *The constructor TrackedObjects.TrackedObject(int, int, int, int) is undefined*

Here's the full code:

```
HashMap<Integer, TrackedObject> objs= new HashMap<Integer, TrackedObject>();

void setup() {
  size(700, 500); 
  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);

}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (TrackedObject o:objs.values()) {
    o.draw();
  }


}


void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {

  TrackedObject o= new TrackedObject(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height),       50, 50);
  o.fillCol=color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
  objs.put(new Integer(tobj.getSymbolID()), o);
}
```

Comment: You have not defined a constructor for TrackedObject that takes 4 integer values.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you didnt create a constructor in your `TrackedObject` class that will accept 4 ints

**problem:**

```
  TrackedObject o= new TrackedObject(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height),       50, 50);
```

**solution:**

create a construtor that will accept 4 ints

```
public TrackedObject(int i, int i2, int i3, int i4)
{
}
```

Comment: I just did but i got this anpther error - expecting "class" found "trackedObject"